# More Efficient Name Querying

Tags: php, mysql, database

My question is simple, but the solution I believe is not as simple.

So, I'm looking for an effective way to query the `students` table using the names of the students using PHP and mySQL. Currently, I have this code :

```
 SELECT * from students 
 WHERE student_number='$searchKey' //can also search using student number
 OR student_fname LIKE '%$searchKey%'
 OR student_lname LIKE '%$searchKey%'
 OR concat(student_lname,' ',student_fname) LIKE '%$searchkey%'
```

Where `$searchKey` is the search variable. This type of database query is effective enough for one-word or one-name first names.

The problem is, what if I'm looking for "John James Smith", but I only know his name as "John Smith"? How can I still retrieve that "John James Smith" records? All the answers will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In MySQL, there is specially designed [FULLTEXT INDEXING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) for that purposes.

Comment: Take care: this looks like being wide open to sql injections...

Comment: @arkascha Not really. The search variable goes thru different filtrations before it becomes the $searchKey which I throw to the function :) Plus, I use CodeIgniter active records, which escapes variables automatically.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo How can I modify the table to allow fulltext indexing?

Comment: @ChristianCastillo did you read the manual page via link I've posted above?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Still studying it, but I guess I can take it from the link you posted. Thanks :)

Comment: Fulltext indexes are great, but make sure your tables are MyISAM and not innoDB

Comment: @Buchow_PHP I'm sorry, I'm not yet a pro in this thing (I'm still a student haha). I read somewhere the difference between the two. I'm using InnoDB. So I'm guessing there would be problems since I cannot just change my table to MyISAM? If that's the case, then what solution could I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying swapping spaces for `%`

```
LIKE "%John%Smith%"
```

Will return "John James Smith"

To swap the character you could do this:

```
$searchKey = str_replace(' ', '%', $searchKey);
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. But I have a question..how can I swap it? A variable is thrown with the keyword as its value, so how can I actually swap the spaces with the wildcard?

Answer (score 0):

try WHERE (student_number+student_fname +student_lname) like '%$searchKey%'